# extends Java class

Tags: java, android, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

I'm trying to use the `GPUImage` android class. I have already built an android app around this but I need to add some additional feature to the `GPUImage` class.

To do so I have done :

```
public class GPUImageExt extends GPUImage {
}
```

I need to override some of them but I also have to add some new methods.

For example a `SavedListener` exists and I need to add an additional listener.

Unfortunately, I got an issue saying :

`There is no default constructor available in co.jp.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImage`

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to decide which existing constructors of `GPUImage` to call from the constructors of your sub-class.

For example, since `GPUImage` has a constructor that takes a single parameter of type `Context`, you can have in your sub-class a constructor :

```
public GPUImageExt (Context context)
{
    super (context);
    ...
}
```

or :

```
public GPUImageExt (Context context, SomeOtherType someOtherParam)
{
    super (context);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the source [here](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/blob/master/library/src/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage/GPUImage.java)

Try this

```
public GPUImageExt( final Context context )
{
    super( context );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructors must call the declared constructors of `GPUImage`

`public GPUImage(final Context context)`

You may want to consider if you want to be subclassing GPUImage at all, rather than wrapping it in something and using composition/delegation.

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor, is a constructor that takes no arguments, so just add one to your class, even if you won't use it.

```
public class GPUImageExt extends GPUImage {
Context context;

public GPUImageExt (Context context)
{
super (context);
this.context = context;
...
}
//default constructor
GPUImageExt(){
super(context);
}

}
```